# How to add key/value pair in hash with ruby laungage

Tags: ruby, json

I am using ruby 2.0.0, At present i have one demo.json file with following hash values:

```
{
   "users": 
   {
      "@jon" : 
      {
        "name": "pradeep",
        "Email": "pradeep@yahoo.com",
        "area": "@jon",
        "location": "@newyork"
      },

      "@smith" : 
     {
      "name": "Smith",
      "Email": "Joe@yahoo.com",
      "area": "@smith",
      "location": "@lverginia"
     }
  }
}
```

now i am taking json values in object using following codes:

```
require 'json'
json = File.read('demo.json')
obj = JSON.parse(json)
```

here @jon and @smith is usernames, Now i wants to take usernames via keyboard inputs and than all the other values inside of @jon with same keyboard.

Suppose i have one new user @david and his other values are like:

```
    "name": "pradeep",
    "Email": "pradeep@yahoo.com",
    "area": "@jon",
    "location": "@newyork"
```

i wants to add this in above demo.json file without remove other values, Any idea how can i do?

I tried to do this in this way:

```
obj["users"]
```

But as i got username via input so i cant hard code username after user key on "obj" object, Hope this make sense..

Comment: What is the problem? Inputting the values with the keyboard or storing the result in the hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this [`JSON`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) also .

I'd do as below :

```
require 'json'

json = JSON.parse(File.read("test.json"))

new_information_arry = ["users", "name", "Email", "area", "location"].map do |elem|
   puts "please give the value of #{elem}"
   [elem,gets.chomp]
end

new_information_hash = Hash[new_information_arry[1..-1]]
json['users'][new_information_arry.first.last] = new_information_hash 

File.write("outputfile.json",JSON.pretty_generate(json))
```

I put the below content to my file `'test.json'` :

```
{
   "users": 
   {
      "@jon" : 
      {
        "name": "pradeep",
        "Email": "pradeep@yahoo.com",
        "area": "@jon",
        "location": "@newyork"
      },

      "@smith" : 
     {
      "name": "Smith",
      "Email": "Joe@yahoo.com",
      "area": "@smith",
      "location": "@lverginia"
     }
  }
}
```

Then I ran the above code as below :

```
please give the value of users
@david
please give the value of name
pradeep
please give the value of Email
pradeep@yahoo.com
please give the value of area
@jon
please give the value of location
@newyor
```

And now my output file `outputfile.json` contains :

```
{
  "users": {
    "@jon": {
      "name": "pradeep",
      "Email": "pradeep@yahoo.com",
      "area": "@jon",
      "location": "@newyork"
    },
    "@smith": {
      "name": "Smith",
      "Email": "Joe@yahoo.com",
      "area": "@smith",
      "location": "@lverginia"
    },
    "@david": {
      "name": "pradeep",
      "Email": "pradeep@yahoo.com",
      "area": "@jon",
      "location": "@newyor"
    }
  }
}
```